# How to change name attribut value from twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using Symfony version 2.3 and twig version 1.0. and I'm trying to change the name attribut value. Here is my code :

```
<div class="control-group">
  {{ form_label(form.menuTitle, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.menuTitle)}}
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="span12">
        {{ form_widget(form.menuTitle, {'attr': {'class': 'span6'}}) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The rendering code :

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label required" for="smart_contactbundle_contact_menuTitle">Menu title</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="span12">
      <input type="text" id="smart_contactbundle_contact_menuTitle" name="smart_contactbundle_contact[menuTitle]" required="required" maxlength="255" class="span6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change   `name="smart_contactbundle_contact[menuTitle]"` to `name="menuTitle"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do that, there's a good possibility that your form won't submit correctly.

However...

If you really want to do it:

```
{{ form_widget(form.menuTitle, {'full_name': 'menuTitle'}) }}
```

Should get you where you want to be.

A full list of available form variables can be found here:

- [Form Variables Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#reference-form-twig-variables)

Comment: ok if i don't change the name attributs, can you show me an example how to validate fields without using jquery and without using the name attributs

Comment: Assuming you've used the correct type in your FormBuilder, it will add HTML5 validation for you. `->add('email', 'email')` (the second option being the type of form field to add) will automatically add `type="email"` to the form input and browsers that enforce it will validate the field input as an email address.